# Is there a better way to write this function for generating random names?

Tags: javascript

```
let names = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    names.push(randomFullName({middleName: true}))
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is basically generate a list of random names and add it to the names array. I'm newish to Javascript so just trying to see if there are ways I can improve my code.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in this code. I also don't really see much code. But if you want a number of things and thus make a loop that generates the things, that seems normal.

Answer (score 0):

What you did is fine. That's how I, and most other devs would probably do it. It's readable and neat.

If you just want something short, you could create an empty array use map...

```
let names = new Array(20).fill(null).map(_=>randomFullName({middleName: true}));
```

Comment: `new Array(20).map()` will not do anything because `new Array(20)` produces an array with 20 empty slots and `.map()` doesn't go over empty slots. You either need to put something in the slots them map, e.g., `.fill(null).map()` (I find this ugly) or use `Array.from(Array(20), _=>randomFullName({middleName: true}))` (or `{length: 20}` instead of making an array). But not sure it's much better either way. https://jsbin.com/qowidaz/edit?js,console